# Adding a UIViewController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, spritebuilder

I have created a new class in another file in Swift. The second class is a UIViewController that will have mediaPickers in. I want to add this viewController to scene, but I can't figure out how.

I have tried

```
  MyViewController().viewDidLoad()
```

and

```
  MyViewController().viewDidLoad(YES)
```

However, both of these call the methods without adding the viewController  to the scene. Any ideas of how to load the viewController?

Thanks

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import MediaPlayer

class mediaViewController: UIViewController, MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate, AVAudioPlayerDelegate
{
   var musicPlayer : MPMusicPlayerController?
   var mediaPicker : MPMediaPickerController?
   var subViewLoad : UIView?

   override func viewDidLoad()
  {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    subViewLoad?.inputView
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)
{
    displayMediaPickerAndPlayItem()
}

func displayMediaPickerAndPlayItem()
{
    mediaPicker = MPMediaPickerController(mediaTypes: .AnyAudio)

    if let picker = mediaPicker
    {
        print("Successfully instantiated a media picker")
        picker.delegate = self
        picker.allowsPickingMultipleItems = true
        picker.showsCloudItems = true
        picker.prompt = "Pick a song please..."
        view.addSubview(picker.view)

        presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else
    {
        print("Could not instantiate a media picker")
    }
}
}
```

I have created this file in swift and added it to my SpriteBuilder project. The SpriteBuilder main scene is a CCNode. From here I want to loa a UIViewController so that I can add a add the mediaPicker to the view.

Comment: NEVER EVER EVER call `viewDidLoad`

Comment: A controller does not have mediaPickers in it, a view has. The controller has references to those. You need to create an instance of the view+controller, using storyboards, or loading it from a nib or anything, but certainly not the way you currently do it.

Comment: I have just tried calling the showMediaPicker directly and get a warning 'MusicPlayer[330:29023] Warning: Attempt to present <MPMediaPickerController: 0x12562cf50> on <MusicPlayer.mediaViewController: 0x12562cc80> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!'

Comment: Could you be clearer with the question ? And maybe show some more source code ? Also we never call the viewDidLoad method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else that was interested in the answer to this, what I done was to get the rootViewController and add a UIView to that.

```
 let presentedVC = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController
```